# How to get Identification of GroupMember of Exchange email using EWS?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get Identification of all the group members of Custom Group(user created groups). I have tried by following.
I get null in member.Id field. I want to use Id for contact identification.

```
foreach (var contactEntity in service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContactGroup contactGroup = contactEntity as Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContactGroup;
        case ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1:
                    ExpandGroupResults groupResults
                        = service.ExpandGroup((contactGroup.Id));
                    List<Entity.Contact> groupMembers = new List<Entity.Contact>();
                    foreach (var member in groupResults)
                    {
                        Entity.Contact objContact = new WorkBook.Data.Entity.Contact();
                        objContact.DisplayName = member.Name;
                        objContact.Email = member.Address;
                        objContact.ExchangeContactId = member.Id.ToString();  //get null
                        groupMembers.Add(objContact);
                    }
                    break;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can an underlying Id returned will depend on the recipient type for each contact Group Member. Eg with contact groups you can add OneOff addresses https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842281.aspx meaning there is no underlying Contact for which to return an Id for so a null result would be expected in this case. The EmailAddress should be the key in that situation.

cheers
Glen